# How to transfer many files using sdb pull

Tags: linux, bash, tizen

#### Get the files all at once

I can copy all files from the smart watch using

```
sdb -s $deviceID pull /opt/usr/media/Documents/ location/on/pc
```

Which works like a charm for less than about 100 files.
However, currently I want to copy 229 files and the command *sometimes* returns error code `225`, `fatal: failed to read '/opt/usr/media/Documents/0163.json': connection fails`, sometimes the command exits without error (without having copied all files).

```
sdb -s $deviceID shell ls /opt/usr/media/Documents/
```

lists all the files I expect to see.

#### Get the files one by one

I also tried

```
for filename in $(sdb -s $deviceID shell ls /opt/usr/media/Documents/); 
do
    sdb -s $smartwatchID pull /opt/usr/media/Documents/$filename
    echo $?
done
```

Some of the `sdb` commands return with exit code `1` and the error message `': unknown reasonget status of /opt/usr/media/Documents/0186.json`,
others return code 0 and no message.

What happens here?

Comment: Workaround: Use Tizen Studio's Connection Explorer to download the files.

Comment: where's the reference of local directory in "sdb -s $smartwatchID pull /opt/usr/media/Documents/$filename" this line?

Comment: Do you mean working directory? It's in the directory where I want the files to be downloaded to, i.e. some sub dir of my home.

Comment: I meant the directory of your dev machine in which you're trying to pull the files from the remote device.

Comment: ~/d0/data/raw/smartwatch/

Comment: So, shouldn't you write the sdb pull command inside the for loop like this "sdb -s $deviceID pull /opt/usr/media/Documents/ location/on/pc" ?

Comment: no because I run the script from that directory (it's my working directory). It doesn't matter at the end, since it should download the file to any directory I have writing access to.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find any noticeable information about this error on internet. Please share here if you could find!